# what does the directory "/etc/ss/certs" contain?

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate

I  open the  directory  "/etc/ss/certs".
It contains a list  of certificates.
What  are  they used for?

Comment: Doesn't exist on my system. Nor does `/etc/ssl/certs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it may be possible to find out this from package system info (it is distribution-specific, though). For instance, for ubuntu/debian you may do the following:

1. Find out package that owns file/directory of interest:

   ```
   $ dpkg --search /etc/ssl/certs
   ca-certificates, openssl, ssl-cert: /etc/ssl/certs
   ```
2. Read package description:

   ```
   $apt-cache show ca-certificates
   Package: ca-certificates
   ...
   Description: Common CA certificates
   This package includes PEM files of CA certificates to allow SSL-based
   applications to check for the authenticity of SSL connections.
   .
   It includes, among others, certificate authorities used by the Debian
   infrastructure and those shipped with Mozilla's browsers.
   .
   Please note that certificate authorities whose certificates are
   included in this package are not in any way audited for
   trustworthiness and RFC 3647 compliance, and that full responsibility
   to assess them belongs to the local system administrator.
   ```